# Native thread exited without detaching

Tags: android, media-player, threadpool

I want to play stream video using this code and vitamio lib

when I run this code it make exception

this is code

```
private void playVideo(String path) {
    doCleanUp();
    try {
        if (path == "") {
            // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Please edit Your Path,"
                            + " and set the path variable to your media file URL.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        } else {
            // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "PlayVideoException");
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "sorry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);
}

public long getCurrentPosition() {
    return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public long getDuration() {
    return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int whatError, int extra) {
    if (whatError == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Media Error, Server Died " + extra);
    } else if (whatError == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Media Error, Error Unknown " + extra);
    }
    isVideoError = true;
    return false;
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    onComplete = true;
    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    Log.i(TAG, "onCompletion called");
}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height
                + ")");
        return;
    }
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
    try {
        doTimerTaskforVideo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated created Exception");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    TRS.RssTimer.cancel();
    VideoTimer.cancel();
    XMLTimer.cancel();
    surfaceDestroyed(holder);
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer = null;
    doCleanUp();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void doCleanUp() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
}

private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

and exception is:

```
05-17 20:17:55.715: E/dalvikvm(21042): threadid=17: native thread exited without detaching
05-17 20:17:55.715: E/dalvikvm(21042): VM aborting
05-17 20:17:55.715: A/libc(21042): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 21543 (helnix.signage)
```

How I can determine what thread that make that exception and how to prevent this exception

In same project now show this exception

```
05-18 16:58:44.080: E/Vitamio[4.2.1][Player](4327): stop called in state 4
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found a solution?